# Остановить while(true)

Tags: action, while, .net-4.0, controller, события

Может, кто подскажет, такая ситуация... В контроллере есть метод с бесконечным циклом. =) Нужно его как-то застопить при уходе со странички, чтобы он в памяти не висел... Нашёл только **ClientDisconnectedToken**, но это для .net 4.5, а в моём проекте .net 4=(

**Обновление**

В контроллере метод, к примеру, refresh, в котором есть цикл `while(true){}`. Ситуация такая, при уходе на другой контроллер этот цикл (объект) продолжает висеть в памяти и крутиться. А нужно как-то бряку повесить на цикл при уходе со странички, что-то типа флага, споймать событие и т.п. Так понятнее? :)

В .net 4.5 нашёл вот такой флажок, так сказать, "свойство ClientDisconnectedToken класса HttpResponseBase / HttpResponse", а в .net 4 подобного не нашёл. =(

Comment: @Artsiom, не совсем ясна проблема. Приведите пример кода.

Comment: @Павел Зайцев, Обновил вопрос.

Comment: @Artsiom, Я думаю правильнее будет совсем избавится от цикла, а не искать способ как его завершить. Тем более, на события "ухода пользователя" нельзя полагаться.

Comment: @Павел Зайцев ну, от цикла я не могу отказаться, т.к. юзаю SSE... мне нужен постоянно открытый канал, пока юзер находится на страничке. Эх, так что-нибудь можете подсказать насчёт аналога ClientDisconnectedToken только для .net 4?